# type 'List<dynamic>'is not a subtypeof type 'List<StatelessWidget>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: the code]

What's wrong with my code and why the error?

```
type 'List<dynamic>'is not a subtypeof type 'List<StatelessWidget>' of 
'function result'
```

Comment: please copy and paste your code instead of printing

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with the type match. I guess somewhere in your code you are giving invalid input to the listview. you can map your list view into a widget list.

```
    yourList.map<Widget>((item) {
  return new ListTile(
    title: new Text(item['title']),
    subtitle: new Text("subTitle"),
  );
}).toList()
```